# Switch MDI to SDI in RStudio

Tags: rstudio

I installed RStudio version Version 0.98.1091 (os: Windows 7) with MDI option. Now I want to change it to the SDI. But I can't find the option anywhere. It should be under edit menu (according to google search) but not any more. I guess new version put it somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't a MDI/SDI option in RStudio - it's just one big one window (I guess that means SDI is your only option).

If you're using the R GUI, you'll find the MDI/SDI options under Edit->GUI Preferences.

Comment: You are right. I just installed RStudio to another PC and there was no MDI/SDI option.